# Approach of: $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-\xi \sin(x)}dx$, when $ \xi \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for a justification to show that
$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-\xi \sin(x)}dx \to 0$$ when $\xi \to \infty$

Here $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Why do you think you can find a closed form of it ?

Comment: For small $\epsilon,\,\xi$, the integrand approximates $1-\xi\sin x$, so the integral approximates $\epsilon-\xi(1-\cos\epsilon)$.

Comment: But $\xi$ can be big!!

Comment: No elementary antiderivative exists. You need to specify whether or not you want approximations or asymptotic relations, and if so - for which sizes of $\varepsilon$ and $\xi$?

Comment: @surb I'm wanting to see if this integral converges to zero when $\xi \to \infty$

Comment: @FShrike edited, thank you!!

Comment: Depending on the size of $\varepsilon$, use variations on the inequality $\sin(x)\ge\frac{2}{\pi}x$ on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Definitely does not converge to zero if $\xi \to \infty$ since on $[\pi,2\pi]$ since is negative (so $-\xi sinx$ is positive and raised to $e$ becomes large there)

Comment: This is an interesting question. I suggest you edit in your work/ thoughts to avoid having the question closed

Comment: As $ξ\to\infty$, $e^{-ξ\sin(x)}\to0$, so the integral approaches $0,\sin(x)>0$. See [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+a-%3Einfty+exp%28-a+sin%28x%29%29). Right?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is small we can approximate the integral for large $\xi$ as $\int_0^\epsilon e^{-\xi x}dx=\frac{1-e^{-\xi\epsilon}}{\xi}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{\xi}$ if $\xi\epsilon$ is large but $\epsilon$ is still small. But the behaviour for larger $\epsilon$ is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

if $\epsilon$ is between $0$ and $\pi$ then one observes that the integrand is bounded by 1 which we take to be our dominating function, then by dominated convergence we can take the limit inside the integral. The integrand converges pointwise to 0 (except at possibly two points but that doesn't matter) hence the integral is zero. if $\epsilon$ is greater than $\pi$ then it diverges since the sequence will be strictly increasing and unbounded.

To be more concrete, suppose for instance $\epsilon$ is between $\pi$ and $3\pi/2$ then by jordan's inequality we get that $sin(x) \ge 2/\pi (x-\pi) $ hence we get that $e^{rsin(x)} \ge e^{r2/\pi (x-\pi)}$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$. The integral of $e^{r2/\pi (x-\pi)}$ diverges as r goes to infinity. Hence so does $e^{rsin(x)}$.